# Faded text not reappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a random wiki viewer, and its been a slog, but i'm finally at the point where i think that at least the UI's functionality is done. The only problem is that after i fade some text on the "random" button, and replace it with an iframe which is then removed when the button is clicked again, the text doesn't seem to fade back in. Any ideas?

https://codepen.io/EpicTriffid/pen/WOYrzg

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Random Button

  var but1status = "closed"
  var randFrame = ("#randframe")

  $(".button1").on("click",function () {
    var but = $(".button1");
    var cross = $("#cross1");
    but.animate({marginTop:"10%", width:"100%", height:"100vh"}, "fast");
    $(".b1text").animate({opacity:0});
    cross.delay(1000).fadeIn();
    but1status = "open"
    if (but1status == "open") {
      setTimeout(randFrame,1000)
      function randFrame (){
        $(".button1").html("<iframe class='randframe' src='demo_iframe.htm' height='100%' width='100%' style='border:none'></iframe>");
        $("#cross1").click(function() {
          $('.button1').removeAttr('style');          
          $("#cross1").fadeOut('fast');
          $('.randframe').remove();
          $(".b1text").animate({opacity:"1"});
        });
      };
    };
  });
```

Comment: Replacing content that you need again later is not really a good strategy. It's more usual, and more sensible, to hide the content, and later simply show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are emptying the HTML of `.button1` when you do:

`$(".button1").html(....`

In order to get it back, you need to add:

`$(".button1").html('<div class="b1text">Random</div>');`

after

`$('.randframe').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

Your button is missing the text `Random`

When you call:

```
$(".button1").html(...
```

you are replacing the inside html of the object with the iframe.

When you remove `.randframe` you need then re-add the text for your button.

Instead of:

```
$('.randframe').remove()
```

you can call this which will accomplish both:

```
$('.button1').html('random');
```

Efficiency tip: You did a good job of saving references to your jquery variables `but` and `cross`, why not use them?

```
but.html(...
cross.click(function (){...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using callbacks. So change your #cross1 fadout to

```
$("#cross1").fadeOut('fast',function(){
  $('.randframe').remove();
  $(".b1text").animate({opacity:"1"});
});
```

Also, this may not be affecting your code, but you're missing some semi colons after some variable declarations.

Not all methods have callbacks in JQuery, but when available, they are useful because basically it means that your code is not fired until the other thing is completely done. This happens a lot with fading and opacity.

Answer (score 0):

This line effectively replaces whatever you have in the button 1 div

```
$(".button1").html("<iframe class='randframe' src='demo_iframe.htm' height='100%' width='100%' style='border:none'></iframe>");
```

Your cross1.click function does not re-populate the button1 div, I would recommend

```
$("#cross1").click(function() {
  $('.button1').removeAttr('style');
  $('.button1').html('Random');
  $("#cross1").fadeOut('fast');
  $(".b1text").animate({opacity:"1"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://codepen.io/Shiladitya/pen/WOLNpw

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  //Random Button
  
  var but1status = "closed"
  var randFrame = ("#randframe")
  
  $(".button1").on("click",function () {
    var but = $(".button1");
    var cross = $("#cross1");
    but.animate({marginTop:"10%", width:"100%", height:"100vh"}, "fast");
    $(".b1text").fadeOut();
    cross.delay(1000).fadeIn();
    but1status = "open"
    if (but1status == "open") {
      setTimeout(randFrame,1000)
      function randFrame (){
        $(".button1").html("<iframe class='randframe' src='demo_iframe.htm' height='100%' width='100%' style='border:none'></iframe>");
        $("#cross1").click(function() {
          but.removeAttr('style');
          cross.fadeOut('fast');
          $('.randframe').remove();
          but.html('<div class="b1text">Random</div>');
        });
      };
    };
  });
  
  
  
  //Search Button
  
  var but2 = "closed"
  
  $(".button2").click(function () {
    var but = $(".button2");
    var btext = $(".b2text");
    var cross = $("#cross2");
    but.animate({marginTop:"10%", width:"100%", height:"100vh"}, "fast");
    btext.fadeOut();
    cross.delay(2000).fadeIn()
    but2 = "open"
    
    $("#cross2").click(function() {
      $('.button2').removeAttr('style');      
      $('.b2text').fadeIn(1500);
      $("#cross2").fadeOut('fast');
    })
  })
                     
  
  
  
  
  
});
```

```css
#spacer { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:50px; 
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:4em;
  padding:0;
  background-color: teal;
}
h1 {
  color:white;
  font-family:"cabin";
  text-align:center;
}
#cross1 {
  position:relative;
  font-size:3em;
  color:white;
  margin-top:6px;
  float: left;
  display:none;
}
#cross2 {
  position:relative;
  font-size:3em;
  color:white;
  margin-top:6px;
  float: right;
  display:none;
}
#randframe {
  display:none;
}
.button1 {
  position:absolute;
  height:2.6em;
  width:5em;
  
  font-size:1.5em;
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  font-family:"cabin";
  
  border:solid;
  border-radius:25px;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
.button2 {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  height:2.6em;
  width:5em;
  
  font-size:1.5em;
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  font-family:"cabin";
  
  border:solid;
  border-radius:25px;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>Wiki Viewer</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="spacer"></div>

<div class="container">  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="button1">
        <div class="b1text">Random</div>
      </div>
      <div class="button2">
        <div class="b2text">Search</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-center">
        <i id="cross1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="text-center">
        <i id="cross2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to keep the content inside the ".button1" to reuse after the iframe is removed.